# JPA Fetcing OffsetDateTime with ZoneOffset - hibernate detects change on field on save

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate

I have a Postgres table with a column **created_at** that keeps triggering updates of row.

```
created_at  TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL
```

In Product entity bean:

```
@Column(name = "created_at")
@NotNull
private OffsetDateTime createdAt;
```

Value in JSON:

```
batchProduct/createdAt in JSON: 2022-06-12T06:19:26Z
```

Map to entity using OffsetDateTime.parse:

```
product.setCreatedAt(OffsetDateTime.parse(batchProduct.getCreatedAt()));
```

When loading multiple time same object(CreatedAt) from same JSON ( **2022-06-12T06:19:26Z**)
hibernate detects change I presume because the database returns the value with offset of my time zone
( **2022-06-12T08:19:26+02:00**). This is the same point in time just representation is
different database has +02:00 and hour is diffrent. Equal is working fine I have tested it:

```
if(product.getCreatedAt().equals(OffsetDateTime.parse(batchProduct.getCreatedAt()))){
       log.info("Product.createAt: " + product.getCreatedAt());
       log.info("BatchProduct.createAt: " + OffsetDateTime.parse(batchProduct.getCreatedAt()));
    } else {
        log.info("Product.createAt: " + product.getCreatedAt());
        log.info("BatchProduct.createAt: " + OffsetDateTime.parse(batchProduct.getCreatedAt()));
        log.info("Objects are equals");
    }

2022-06-12 12:00:10,953 [main] INFO  c.xxx.mapper.BatchObjectsMapper - Product.createAt: 2022-06-12T08:19:26+02:00
2022-06-12 12:00:10,953 [main] INFO  c.xxx.mapper.BatchObjectsMapper - BatchProduct.createAt: 2022-06-12T06:19:26Z
2022-06-12 12:00:10,953 [main] INFO  c.xxx.mapper.BatchObjectsMapper - Objects are equals
```

When I save the same object over and over it always triggers an update of the row in the database ( and values in DB are the same), when I comment setCreatedAt ( there are many more attributes) DB is not updated ( hibernate detects this is the same object) and this is wanted behavior.

The question is: how is Hibernate checking if the OffsetDateTime is equal because it keeps triggering updates of entity for same OffsetDateTime?

Comment: For the `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` type, Postgres *always* stores the values in UTC, and returns the values in UTC. By “in UTC”, I mean an offset from UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds. If you see a value retrieved from a Postgres column of that type with an offset other than zero, then your tooling or middleware changed the value retrieved from Postgres.

Comment: Hm.. this is not the case I get 2022-06-12 12:00:10,953 [main] INFO  c.xxx.mapper.BatchObjectsMapper - Product.createAt: 2022-06-12T08:19:26+02:00. I have hibernate - latest SpringBoot ... nothing in middle

Comment: “I have hibernate - latest SpringBoot” — so you have *much* in the middle. Write a throwaway app that does nothing more than make a simple JDBC connection to retrieve an `OffsetDateTime` object from your `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` column. No Spring, no Hibernate, no ORM, no database framework. You’ll see an offset of zero.

Answer (score 0):

This is not direct answer to your question but it can helps with your problem.

You may try Hibernate 6 with new approach for working with `OffsetDateTime`

First of all you need to add column for storing offsets.

```sql
-- the old one with time zone
created_at  TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL
-- and the new one
created_at_tz_offset INTEGER NOT NULL
```

And then change your entity to

```java
@Column(name = "created_at")
@NotNull
@TimeZoneStorage(TimeZoneStorageType.COLUMN)
@TimeZoneColumn(name = "created_at_tz_offset")  
private OffsetDateTime createdAt;
```

After that `OffsetDateTime` value will not depends on your JVM timezone or PostgreSQL timezone it will be the same for different timezones.

more information is this article [Improved OffsetDateTime and ZonedDateTime Mapping in Hibernate 6](https://thorben-janssen.com/hibernate-6-offsetdatetime-and-zoneddatetime/)